# Using ListView and ArrayAdapter crashes application

Tags: listview, android-arrayadapter

I am new to android still learning basics
trying to use ListView and ArrayAdapter
here is my main_activity code
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //fake data initilization
     String[] fakeData=new String[]{"froyo",
                        "gingerbread",
                        "honycomb",
                        "icecream",
    "jellybean"};
    ArrayList<String> items=new ArrayList<String>();
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<fakeData.length;i++)
    items.add(fakeData[i]);
    //adapter initilization
     ArrayAdapter<String> ap=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_layout,items);



    ListView check=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.checked);
    check.setAdapter(ap);
} }
```

and my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/checked"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

why does application crashes and fix for it would be helpfull thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout you're using to initialize the adapter, is that the activity's layout? Because you need to use a separate layout to display the data. See,

[Using Array Adapters for ListViews](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView)

Comment: i did changes accordingly but result is same app crash

Comment: Can you post log messages

Comment: i got it what you said was true i needed separate text layout for listview.Thanx